# In Java, is there a way to track if a variable, a method or a class created in Heap or Stack?

Tags: java, memory, heap-memory, stack-memory

I am trying to fully understand how the Java works with its memory arrangement. The discussions on Internet are very confused, and sometimes contradicts each other, so I found no one I can trust. This thing can be very complicate if it mixed with static, static method, local variable, thread, volatile and so on. So I am thinking if there is a way I can study that myself my doing some Java coding experiment. A class MemoryTrack does something like this,

```
public myMethod(){
int i = 0;
MemoryTrack.show(new myClass()); //print out "Heap at address 111"
MemoryTrack.show(new myClass()); //print out "Heap at address 222"
MemoryTrack.show(i); //print out "Stack at address 333"
MemoryTrack.show("a static method");  //print out "stack at address 444"
}
```

Comment: why not post this as the answer?

Comment: In any event, part of the point of Java is that you shouldn't care what's on the heap and what's on the stack -- indeed, the JIT can sometimes figure out that something can go on the stack that would normally go on the heap.

Comment: @LouisWasserman It can matter in certain large-scope applications, but for the majority of cases it does not.

Answer (score 7):

The use of memory is described in [Section 2.5 of the Java Virtual Machine Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.5). The stack stores stack frames (containing local variables and partial results). The heap is where all class instances and arrays come from. Stack frames can also be allocated from the heap (and then pushed onto the stack). There are also method areas and runtime constant pool memory. The details are spelled out in the spec.

As far as monitoring memory usage, several profilers have tools for that. For monitoring from within the program, take a look at the [MemoryMXBean](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/management/MemoryMXBean.html) class (and related classes in the `java.lang.management` package). It's very easy to use. While it probably doesn't give you everything that it sounds like you want, but it's probably the best thing available.

Answer (score 3):

The rule is pretty simple: heap contains objects, stack contains local variables and method parameters. Object fields are inside the objects, in the heap. Don't know about static fields. Methods and constructors are not stored in the stack, nor in the heap. Threads and volatile don't matter.

Method *calls* are on the stack. Each has a space reserved to it, the *stack frame*, that contains the local variables and the parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Two things you need to know

- its not as complicated as you think.
- it doesn't matter 99% of the time.

---

Variables are always on the stack.

Objects are always on the heap. (There are exceptions but I wouldn't worry about them)

Methods and classes are always in the perm gen.

In the HotSpot/OpenJDK JVM, static fields are collected in a singleton object for the class. You can see the instance if you do a heap dump. Other JVMs may do this differently.

> A class MemoryTrack does something like this,

Such a method wouldn't do anything useful as the argument will always be on the stack and object it refers to will always be on the heap.  You can't get the memory location of an Object in a standard way and it unlikely to be useful if it did as it can change at any time.

Answer (score -1):

You may think all variables in Java are on heap. Actually it is implementation dependent.

Comment: Actually, it's pretty well specified in the [Java Virtual Machine Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.5). The only implementation dependent features are the structure of the stack, whether stack frames are allocated from the heap, and a few other issues peripheral to OP's question.

Comment: The above link is for SE 7. The [spec for SE 5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se5.0/html/Overview.doc.html#1732) has pretty much the same language for this topic.